# c# set Property Visible true during run-time and check it

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, visible

I have a problem with property `Visibile` during run-time.

This is my code:

```
var pointPictureBox1 = pictureBox1.Location;
pictureBox1.Visible = true;
if (pictureBox1.Visible == false)
    pictureBox2.Location = pointPictureBox1;
pictureBox2.Visible = true;
```

I set, on WinForm, `Visible` false on `pictureBox1`.

When I try to check the attribute `Visible` returns me that is always set to `false`, even if it imposed to `true`.

I can not understand why this happens, can you help me ?

Comment: In what method do you execute code fragment above?

Comment: The code you have shown looks fine, by any chance is `pictureBox1` in some sort of Container that has `Visible = false`?

Comment: @rudolf_franek in the constructor , maybe I have to move it to the form_load ?

Comment: @haddow64 nope, all components of the form are set visible

Comment: You should move your code to the Form_Load method.

Comment: @ThomasSymalla Yes, I had already moved before and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved my code from `Constructor` to `Form_Load`